# Order the domain so that function is monotonic

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Is there a bijection $b: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f \circ b$ is monotonic?

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to your question: but you may want to look at [symmetric rearrangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_decreasing_rearrangement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $f(x)=x^2$ and suppose $b: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bijection. Let $p,q\in\mathbb R$ be such that $b(p)=-1$, $b(q)=1$. Note that $f(b(p))=(-1)^2=1=f(b(q))$. Consider the case $p<q$ (the other case being similar). Take any $r\in(p,q)$. Then $b(r)\not\in\{-1,1\}$, hence $f(b(r))\not=1$. If $f(b(r))>1$ then $p<r<q$ but $f(b(p))=1<f(b(r))>1=f(b(q))$, 
so $f\circ b$ is not monotonic. If $f(b(r))<1$ then $p<r<q$ but $f(b(p))=1>f(b(r))<1=f(b(q))$, 
so again $f\circ b$ is not monotonic.